# Display messages in bootstrap file

Tags: 7, bootstrapping

I have a file that I have bootstrapped and I am trying to print messages but I can't get it to work. Here is the code does anything look wrong (mysite was changed)?

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/home/mysite/public_html');
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
?>

<html>
<body>
 <div class="description">             
  <?php global $user;

     print "Welcome " . $user->name;
     drupal_set_message(t("Don't panic!"), 'warning');
     print $messages;
  ?>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the list of the messages set with `drupal_set_message()`, you should call [drupal_get_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7).

Drupal doesn't use any global `$messages` to store those messages. They are stored in `$_SESSION['messages']`, but you should really use `drupal_get_messages()`.

`drupal_get_messages()` returns an array; this means you cannot simply use the following code.

```
$messages = drupal_get_messages();
print $messages;
```